# adding nodes to line segments

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, plot

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[active,float]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,plotmarks,arrows,automata,positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture} 
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.8cm,y=0.5cm]
    %axis
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (10,0);
        \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,12);

        %ticks
        \foreach \x in {0,...,10}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,-3pt)     node[anchor=north] {\x};
        \foreach \y in {0,...,12}
            \draw (0pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y)     node[anchor=east] {\y}; 

    %labels      
    \node[below=0.8cm,xshift=0.3cm,scale=1.5] at (x axis mid) {$\sum{t_i}\;\;\longrightarrow$};

    % plot first concave function
    \draw[mark=square*,green,thick,mark options={fill=green}] (0,2) -- (1,3) -- (2,4) -- (3,5) -- (4,5) -- (5,5) -- (6,5) -- (7,5) -- (8,5) -- (9,3) -- (10,1);

    \node[mark=square*,green,thick,mark options={fill=green}] at (4,5) {};

    % plot second concave function
    \draw[mark=square*,red,thick,mark options={fill=red}] (0,1) -- (1,2) -- (2,3) -- (3,4) -- (4,5) -- (5,6) -- (6,6) -- (7,5) -- (8,4) -- (9,3) -- (10,2);

    % plot third concave function
    \draw[mark=*,blue,thick,mark options={fill=blue}] (0,3) -- (1,5) -- (2,7) -- (3,9) -- (4,10) -- (5,11) -- (6,11) -- (7,10) -- (8,9) -- (9,6) -- (10,3);

    %legend 
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5,10)}] 
    \draw[yshift=3\baselineskip] (0,0) -- 
        plot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=red}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{$f(t)$};
    \draw[yshift=2\baselineskip] (0,0) -- 
        plot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=green}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{$g(t)$};
    \draw[yshift=\baselineskip] (0,0) -- 
        plot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=blue}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{$f(t) + g(t)$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

representing the following figure:

[image: The goal figure]

I’m having troubles doing the following:

1. Show the numbers on both x-y axis with a step  of 2
2. For some reason I cannot visualize the nodes between the line segments
3. Cannot add a rectangle area around the legend.

Comment: I would suggest you use `pgfplots` instead of tikz -- this is more of a graph rather than a drawing. To get steps of 2 use `\foreach \x in {0,2,...,10}` instead of `\foreach \x in {0,...,10}`.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments and in Harish's answer, using `pgfplots` allows you to specify the styling once and reuse it in your document rather than reinventing the wheel for every plot.

I created a `cycle list` called `mycycle` that can be used in any plot (with `cycle list name=mycycle` to cycle through plot styles.

The rest of the styling is done in the options to the `axis` environment, but this is easily packaged in a TikZ style for reuse in any other plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycycle}{%
  green!70!black,every mark/.append style={fill=green!80},mark=diamond*\\%
    red!70!black,every mark/.append style={fill=  red!80},mark=square*\\%
   blue!70!black,every mark/.append style={fill= blue!80},mark=*\\%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis lines=left,
  ymin=0,ymax=13.75,
  tick align=inside,
  axis line style={-},
  cycle list name=mycycle,
  legend pos=north west,
  legend cell align=left,
  legend style={
    outer sep=-0.2em,
    inner sep=0.2em,
    node font=\small,
  },
  xlabel={$\sum{t_i}\;\;\longrightarrow$},
]
  \addplot coordinates {
    (0,2) (1,3) (2,4) (3,5) (4,5) (5,5) (6,5) (7,5) (8,5) (9,3) (10,1)
  };
  \addlegendentry{$f(t)$};
  \addplot coordinates {
    (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) (5,6) (6,6) (7,5) (8,4) (9,3) (10,2)
  };
  \addlegendentry{$g(t)$};
  \addplot coordinates {
    (0,3) (1,5) (2,7) (3,9) (4,10) (5,11) (6,11) (7,10) (8,9) (9,6) (10,3)
  };
  \addlegendentry{$f(t)+g(t)$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! you added it, quicker. I had to go for some work. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `pgfplots` for such jobs? Any way, to draw box around legend, you can use `fit` library. The syntax of `plot` is different. To get plot marks you should use coordinates with proper syntax. And for getting tick labels in multiples of `2` change the foreach loop as `{0,2,...,12}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,plotmarks,arrows,automata,positioning,fit,shapes.geometric,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.8cm,y=0.5cm]
    %axis
    \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (x axis mid) (10,0);
        \draw (0,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (0,12);

        %ticks
        \foreach \x in {0,2,...,10}
        \draw (\x,0pt) -- (\x,-3pt)     node[anchor=north] {\x};
        \foreach \y in {0,2,...,12}
            \draw (0pt,\y) -- (-3pt,\y)     node[anchor=east] {\y};

    %labels
    \node[below=0.8cm,xshift=0.3cm,scale=1.5] at (x axis mid) {$\sum{t_i}\;\;\longrightarrow$};

    % plot first concave function
    \draw[green,thick,] plot[mark=square*,mark options={fill=green}] coordinates{(0,2)  (1,3)  (2,4)  (3,5) (4,5)  (5,5)  (6,5)  (7,5)  (8,5) (9,3)  (10,1)};

    \node[mark=square*,green,thick,mark options={fill=green}] at (4,5) {};

    % plot second concave function
    \draw[red,thick] plot[mark=square*,mark options={fill=red}] coordinates {(0,1)  (1,2)  (2,3) (3,4)  (4,5)  (5,6)  (6,6)  (7,5)  (8,4)  (9,3)  (10,2)};

    % plot third concave function
    \draw[blue,thick] plot [mark=*,mark options={fill=blue}] coordinates{(0,3)  (1,5)  (2,7)  (3,9)  (4,10)  (5,11)  (6,11)  (7,10)  (8,9)  (9,6)  (10,3)};

    %legend
    \begin{scope}[shift={(0.5,10)}]
    \draw[yshift=3\baselineskip] (0,0) node(a){} --
        plot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=red}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{$f(t)$};
    \draw[yshift=2\baselineskip] (0,0) --
        plot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=green}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right]{$g(t)$};
    \draw[yshift=\baselineskip] (0,0) --
        plot[mark=square*, mark options={fill=blue}] (0.25,0) -- (0.5,0) node[right](fg){$f(t) + g(t)$};
    \node[draw,fit=(a) (fg)] {};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, you won't need `preview` package explicitly  with `standalone` class.